# Exchange shared mailboxes - on the go

Tags: email, exchange

After implementing a few shared mailboxes, I noticed I can't access them from a mobile device like the iPhone's native Mail client. Is this a limitation of shared mailboxes or lack of interest by Apple and/or third party app developers?

I like the idea of shared mailboxes, but the lack of access to those emails on the go can be troubling for a business that wants to respond quickly to customers. I thought of using aliases instead, but then email management can get tricky if two or more people are supporting that email address.

Comment: I THINK the outlook app does what you need, I don't have time to test with a shared mailbox tho. I'm about to have to turn on airplane mode myself

Answer (score -1):

It is a limit of the way exchange works with shared mailboxes and how 3rd party client handles exchange mailboxes.
Im not sure if its somehow possible in the outlook client as described above, but they can be added as an pop/imap account.

http://goo.gl/N8UYan

Comment: Please quote the relevant material and avoid using url shortners.